# Woocommerce change order of $product->get_categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need order the results of "$product->get_categories()" with the slug.

The template use this code:

```
$cat_count = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) );

//And after...

<?php echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', $cat_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>
```

I've seen in a tutorial, that I can use this code,but doesn't work (in functions.php):

```
function wptt_cat_order( $args ){

    $args['orderby'] = 'slug';
    $args['order'] = 'ASC';
    return $args;

} // wptt_cat_order
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_subcategories_args', 'wptt_cat_order' );
```

Other question I have is(but not is so important than the other question), why he uses the $cat_count in "_n()" function and not "get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' )"? first is only a number O_O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: you can't use that method to order the categories.

You're going to need to write your own loop using [`wp_get_post_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms), which allows you to pass arguments (such as `orderby`). Something like the following should work (but I haven't tested it):

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
);
$product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( $product->id, 'product_cat', $args );
$cat_count = sizeof( $product_cats );

echo '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', $cat_count, 'woocommerce' );
for ( $i = 0; $i < $cat_count; $i++ ) {
    echo $product_cats[$i]->name;
    echo ( $i === $cat_count - 1 ) ? '' : ', ';
}
echo '</span>';
```

Comment: Thanks! When i go to house, I try this! Only one question: Why you use the for loop for print the categories and in my code not is necessary?(only unse the _n() function)

Comment: The [`_n()` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_n) retrieves the plural or single form based on the amount (`$cat_count`). If the count is 1, `Category` will be printed. If the count is > 1, `Categories` will be printed. The `for` loop is used so that the separator `, ` can be conditionally applied (this works better than using a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Ok, I have can try you code, give me the error in line: echo $product_cats[$i]; The error: object of class stdClass could not be converted to string. If I destroy the For, he only print "categories:", not the categories. :(

Comment: I have edited my code on that line to `$product_cats[$i]->name;`. Please try it and let me know if it's still throwing an error.

Comment: Yeah, thats work! Only need change de value of "i var" in for loop to 0, for not ignore the first cat ;) THANKS!!

Comment: Excuse me rnevius, you can help me for convert to link the categories strings? If I use this into the loop: echo get_term_link ($product_cats[$i]->term_id, 'product_cat'); print all the url of caregories, but after last send me error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string

Comment: Hi @Phyron . Please post a new question if you are still running into issues. Thanks.